# Capture timestamped X mouse events, and render a video with custom mouse pointer?

Tags: x11, video, mouse, desktop, recording

I am typically using `recordmydesktop` to record some application interaction; however, on my system, `recordmydesktop` always shows the same mouse pointer/cursor (the arrow) - regardless if, in reality, it changed to (say) a corner arrow when resizing a window. In addition, I'd need something to indicate on the video when a mouse (either button) is pressed, when the button is held down, and when the button is released - which desktops on their own usually don't indicate (unless a given application handles those events).

So, this is what I thought - maybe I can run `recordmydesktop` with the option `--no-cursor` "Disable drawing of the cursor."; and on the other hand, record raw mouse event data (positition and clicks). I found [Record every keystroke and store in a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129159/record-every-keystroke-and-store-in-a-file) and [How to get mouse click position?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137616/how-to-get-mouse-click-position), and so I learned about [Xnee](http://xnee.wordpress.com/) ([manual](http://xnee.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/xnee1.pdf)), which can record all mouse data in a plain text file.

So, I was wondering - short of writing my own parser, is there a program that

- could use a `cnee` (or its own) format recording of mouse data; then
- accept something like a transparent animated .gif for "mouse left/right press/release" events, as well as transparent .png for "left/right down/up" states
- accept a frames per second rate setting, and pixel width and height of output video
- render an image sequence at the requested rate and size, with the specified .gifs/.pngs at the mouse position - as per the recorder mouse data - as the only content of a frame image (which is otherwise transparent)?

Then, I could run `recordmydesktop --no-cursor` and `cnee --record --mouse -o /tmp/xnee.xns` in parallel; after I'm done I'd render a separate transparent "mask" video of the custom mouse pointer motion only; and finally overlay the mouse cursor "mask" with the original video.

Of course, if there is already a program that does this, I'd love to know about it - since even if there is a program to do as I described above, I believe it would be still difficult if one is capturing a desktop area larger than the video size, and wants to use something like `recordmydesktop --follow-mouse` "When this option is enabled, the capture area follows the mouse cursor."

Comment: See also: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/34364/record-and-replay-mouse-clicks