# Cylinder 2 screens config with xrandr

Tags: configuration, xrandr

I've two screens configured with this xrandr command :

```
xrandr --output VGA-0 --primary --mode 1440x900 --output DVI-0 --left-of VGA-0 --mode 1440x900 --rotate normal
```

For now, the mouse is blocked with the right edge of the right screen and with the left edge of the left screen. I want mouse to loop right and left as screens were a cylinder.

But I don't want this to be possible with up and down edges : I don't want a torus, just a cylinder.

Is this possible?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/497104/17531 looks like unity has a wrap option which is what you want.

Comment: Related - https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229701/7453

Comment: Potential solution using xdotool - https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=9768

Comment: Thank you! That's just (almost) perfect! (almost: mouse slightly sticks to the left edge before looping to the right). I'd like to accept your solution... is this actually possible?